# knp_menu_render() & bootstrap template sidebar, keeps expanding, when i go to different page, Why?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sidebar, knpmenubundle

I have a side menu which is part of base.html.twig.
The side bar is inherited and  is  not rendering correctly when i start moving around routes/pages. More specifically All submenu's expand.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">
  <div class="menu_section">
    <h3>General</h3>
      <ul class="nav side-menu">
        <li><a><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>  Accounts <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
           <ul class="nav child_menu">
              {{ knp_menu_render('AppBundle:Builder:mainMenu',{'currentClass':'active'}) }}
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> backup Accounts <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
           <ul class="nav child_menu">
              {{ knp_menu_render('AppBundle:Builder:mainMenu2',{'currentClass':'active'}) }}
           </ul>
         </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the reason for this.

Basically. all end points must be unique and exist for proper functioning of the knp_menu_render